# I'm unable to send emails from Django App on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I'm unable to receive emails from my app after deploying to Aws, My app sits on Ec2 and I host my env on Elastic Bean, The emailing situation works fine locally but not on AWS.
Note: I use Amazon SES

I'm not sure on what to do next at this point, I don't seem to be able to find the problem.

**HERE IS MY SETTINGS FOR EMAIL**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# EMAIL_USE_SSL=True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

**HERE IS MY LOG FILE**

````
django_1  | Exception in thread Thread-184:
django_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
django_1  |     self.run()
django_1  |   File "/build/authentication/utils.py", line 15, in run
django_1  |     self.email.send()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
django_1  |     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
django_1  |     new_conn_created = self.open()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 67, in open
django_1  |     self.connection.starttls(keyfile=self.ssl_keyfile, certfile=self.ssl_certfile)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 769, in starttls
django_1  |     self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 611, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
django_1  |     if not (200 <= self.ehlo()[0] <= 299):
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 451, in ehlo
django_1  |     self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 378, in putcmd
django_1  |     self.send(f'{s}{CRLF}')
django_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 365, in send
django_1  |     raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
django_1  | smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
django_1  | [23/Mar/2022 11:29:11] "POST /api/auth/register HTTP/1.1" 201 1246```
````

Comment: Are there any logs you can share from the ec2 instance to help debug the issue?

Comment: I've provided that

Comment: Have you tried their suggestion of "please run connect() first"? If so, what was the outcome? If it's for sure not code-wise, check your security groups if your EC2 instance is able to connect to the email host at all. Maybe you can even try that from the EC2 instance itself if you can ssh into it.